# Appendix as regular \chapter; Appendixes as \section within Chapter-Appendix but with \alph chapter number

Tags: numbering, appendices

I'd like to have something like this

```
1. Chapter 1
  1.1. Section 1.1
  1.2. Section 1.2
2. Chapter 2
...
7. Appendix
  A. Appendix 1
  B. Appendix 1
```

Im trying it like this:

```
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section 1.1}
\section{Section 1.2}
\chapter{Chapter 2}
...
\chapter{Appendix}
\renewcommand\thechapter{\Alph{section}}
\section{Appendix 1}
\section{Appendix 2}
```

But the result is

```
1. Chapter 1
  1.1. Section 1.1
  1.2. Section 1.2
2. Chapter 2
...
7. Appendix
  A.1 Appendix 1
  B.2 Appendix 1
```

How to get rid of the 1 & 2 in A.1 and B.2?

Comment: You have to `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}`

Answer (score 2):

Easy:

```
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section 1.1}
\section{Section 1.2}
\chapter{Chapter 2}
...
\chapter{Appendix}
\renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section}}
\section{Appendix 1}
\section{Appendix 2}
```